# Loading and extracting entire CSV in Ruby on Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should I go about loading (or updating) a database for my RoR application? This is a "one time" operation, so coding it in the application seems strange.

Also, how do I access the database after the application is running, do the models files sit somewhere on my server, accesible for "read-only"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially can write a script to load data into the database from CSV files.

The following is an example how you can do that:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'

infile  = "db/data/csv/my_data.csv" # location of the file
count   = 0

CSV.open(infile, 'r') do |row|
  col1 = row[1]
  col2 = row[2]

  obj = MyObject.new({ :col1 => col1, :col2  => col2 })
  obj.save

  count += 1
  print '.' if (count % 10) == 0
end 

puts 
puts "Successfully loaded #{count} records into database!"
```

Then run the script using rails [command line tool runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner): `rails runner db/scripts/csv_data_loader.rb`.

Comment: Working with csv is very valuable. At my job I've used and continue to use it for report generation. Gather a collection, iterate over it, format it nicely and there's a report. (And ActiveRecord makes such a thing MUCH easier than using bare SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

The `seeds.rb` is where you put one-time initialization code. You can find it in the `db` sub-directory. This might of interest too: [Database seeding](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding).

If your application is already in production, use migrations.